# Navigation bar doesn't get fixed when using position:fixed

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to set my navigation bar to fixed which is something I've done lots of times before, but for some reason it's not working.

I thought it might do with the fact that I was using a transition, but after deleting the transition the problem does persist.

I am using ReactJS but as I see on CodePen it is not what's causing this.

I created a pen with the code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGzrgj

```
Some(Random.Code) {
    Required(by.StackOverflow(to.post){ 
        this.question
    }
}
```

Reac

As you see nav's got position:fixed but the navigation bar doesn't stay where it is while scrolling.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: not `display:fixed` . true `position:fixed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're not using `position:fixed` as Mr Cavus has observed. You have this:

```
nav {
  display: fixed;
}
```

No such setting, as you already know, or you wouldn't have it as `position: fixed` in your title. You'll want to do something like this:

```
nav {
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you want your menu to be centered.

Comment: Okay, I'm dumb as **** haha, thanks man! I was just obsessed with it because you know sometimes there's wrong code but you just can't see it, again thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @OscarArranz You're welcome. :) We all have those slap-the-forehead moments. Feel free to accept this as the answer, so that other folks will know there's an answer here.

Comment: Sure, I had tried to select it but it was too recent and I hadn't come back since now

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize I answered that quickly.